# Calculating Integrals Using Residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $\int \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  Can I compute this by applying the fact that the denominator has two poles and taking the n-1 derivative of the analytic component at each pole times the n-1st power of the pole?

Comment: What path are you integrating over? AFAICS, you have a choice of closing the integration path either via an arc in the upper *or* in the lower complex plane. In the first case, only the pole at $i$ would matter, and the second one only the pole at $-i$.

Comment: My mistake, the upper complex plane.  I do have a question about that as well: why is it that we can make that choice and still evaluate the integral no problem?  That is, since roots are $+-i$ I would expect that both would need to be considered seperately and their residues added.

Answer (score 2):

To compute $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} \,dx$ via contour integration, you first need to convert it into a complex countour integral. The idea is to look at integrals over paths $\gamma_r$ which start at $-r \in \mathbb{R}$, proceed to $r \in \mathbb{R}$ along the real line, and then back to $-r$ along an arc with radius $r$. If $\alpha_r$ is some suitable parametrization for that arc (doesn't matter which, we won't need it explicitly), you can thus write $$
  \int_\mathbb{[-r,r]}\underbrace{\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}}_{=f(x)} \,dx = \underbrace{\oint_{\gamma_r} f(x) \,dx}_{=G(r)} - \underbrace{\int_{\alpha_r} f(x) \,dx}_{=A(r)} \text{.}
$$

From the residue theorem, you get that  $$
  G(r) = \frac{1}{i2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n} I(\gamma_r,a_k) \textrm{Res}(f,a_k) \text{.}
$$
where $a_k$ are the poles of $f$ and $I(\gamma_r,a_k)$ tells you how many times $\gamma_r$ runs around $a_k$. Depending on whether you closed your integration path in the upper or lower complex plane, you'll get $I(\gamma_r,a_k) = -1$ or $1$ respectively, for those $a_k$ which lie within $\gamma_r$. For all other $a_k$ you get $0$. If you picked the arc on the upper complex plane, you get for $r > 1$ that $$
  G(r) = -\frac{1}{i2\pi}\textrm{Res}(f,i) \text{.}
$$
Note once $r > 1$, $G(r)$ doesn't depends on $r$!, i.e. is constant.

Now look at $A(r)$. In general, the absolut value of a path integral $\int_\zeta g(z)$ is bounded by the length of $\zeta$ times the supremum of $g$'s absolute value along $\zeta$. For $|A(r)|$ that gives you $$
  |A(r)| \leq \pi r \sup_{|x|=r} \left|\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\right| \leq \pi r \left|\frac{1}{(r^2 - 1)^2}\right| \text{.}
$$
It's easy to see that this implies $$
  \lim_{r\to\infty} A(r) = 0 \text{.}
$$

Thus, $$
  \int_\mathbb{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \,dx
  = \lim_{r\to\infty} \int_\mathbb{[-r,r]} f(x) \,dx
  = \lim_{r\to\infty} G(r) - \lim_{r\to\infty} A(r) 
  = -\frac{1}{i2\pi}\textrm{Res}(f,i) \text{.}
$$

If you had picked the arc on the lower complex plane, you'd instead get $$
  = \frac{1}{i2\pi}\textrm{Res}(f,-i)
$$
i.e., you have discovered that, at least for your $f$, the sum of the residues is zero.

Note that the same procedure works for other integrands $f$ too. The only restriction on $f$ is that it needs to be holomorphic except at fininitly many points on either the lower or the upper complex plane, and that $\sup_{|x|=r} f(x) \leq Mr^{-2}$ for some $M$.

To compute the residue $\textrm{Res}(f,a)$, remember that the residue is the coefficient of $x^{-1}$ in the laurent series of $f$ around $a$. If the pole has finite order $n$, you know that for all $k > n$ the coefficient of $x^{-k}$ in that laurent series are zero. By multiplying $f$ with $(x-a)^n$ (which shifts all coefficients by $n$) you thus get a function which is holomorphic at $a$, since it's laurent series no longer has any terms with negative exponents for $x$. In other words, the laurent series is a taylor series. The coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is then the coefficient of $x^{-1}$ in the original series. This yields the following formula for computing the residue, assuming that $f(x)$ has a pole of order $n > 0$ at $a$ $$
  \textrm{Res}(f,a) = \frac{((x-a)^nf(x))^{(n-1)}(a)}{(n-1)!}
$$
Note that $.^{(n-1)}$ means taking the $(n-1)$-th derivative here (with the result being a function, not a value), whereas $.^{n}$ means $n$-th power (with the result being a value of course).

Comment: Thank you, I will have to read this over more carefully.